# Example section in feature file shows duplicate count for the Test Case count in extent report after the execution

Tags: cucumber-java, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3RTX.png)

As Shown in the above image, I'm using Example section to send the test data. But when I use example section after the execution in the extent report Tc is duplicated even though it has been executed only one time. I'm using ExtentCucumberAdapter as shown below

```
`public void clickSignInButtonAndEnterCredentials(String username, String password) {

        DriverManager.getWrapperClass().waitForElementToBeVisible(primarySignInButton);
        DriverManager.getWrapperClass().click(primarySignInButton);
        enterName(username);
        waitForLoginPageLoaderToDisappear();
        enterPassword(password);
        clickSignInButton();
        ExtentCucumberAdapter.addTestStepLog("Entered username "+username+" and Password "+password+"in the Login page");
    }`
```

As shown in the above image, the tc is duplicated. Not sure Where I'm going wrong. Without example section it is working fine.